# Function result auto&&

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type-deduction

I know the meaning of return type `auto` and `decltype(auto)`. Also I know `auto&&` for variable declarations. So I tried `auto&&` as return type:

```
template <class X, class Y>
auto a(X &&x, Y &&y) -> auto {
    return x+y;
}

template <class X, class Y>
auto b(X &&x, Y &&y) -> decltype(auto) {
    return x+y;
}

template <class X, class Y>
auto c(X &&x, Y &&y) -> auto&& {  // <----
    return x+y;
}
```

And it seems to be the same as `decltype(auto)`. Are `b` and `c` the same thing, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b("a"s, "b")` returns a temporary string.

`c("a"s, "b")` returns a dangling reference.